# Add variable value in a JSON string in Python

Tags: python, json

I am puzzled why this is not working. I am trying add my variable value in the JSON and everytime I add it, it is not showing properly in my JSON string.

```
hostname = "machineA.host.com"
```

I need to add the above hostname information to the below JSON document -

```
b"{\"Machine Name\":\"\"+hostname+\"\"}", None, True)
```

But whenever I am adding it in the above way, it is not working at all.

Not sure what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're escaping the inner double quote `"` in your string. It should be:

```
b"{\"Machine Name\":\""+hostname+"\"}", None, True)
```

In python you can also use single quotes `'` for strings - and you don't need to escape double quotes inside single quoted strings

```
b'{"Machine Name":"'+hostname+'"}', None, True)
```

There are two better ways of doing this though. The first is string formatting which inserts a variable into a string:

```
b'{"Machine Name":"%s"}' % hostname # python 2.x (old way)
b'{{"Machine Name":"{0}"}}'.format(hostname) # python >= 2.6 (new way - note the double braces at the ends)
```

The next is with the Python [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module by converting a python `dict` to a JSON string

```
>>> hostname = "machineA.host.com"
>>> data = {'Machine Name': hostname}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"Machine Name": "machineA.host.com"}'
```

This is probably the preferred method as it will handle escaping weird characters in your hostname and other fields, ensuring that you have valid JSON at the end.

Is there a reason you're using a `bytestring`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. For bytestring yes, I am using this with Zookeeper so that's why I need to use bytestring.

Comment: @Peter Gibson: any idea why the following doesn't work:
`'{"Machine Name":"{0}"}'.format("yada")`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '"Machine Name"'

Comment: @JavaSa sorry, when using `.format` the outer braces should be doubled up to avoid triggering the format code. `'{{"Machine Name":"{0}"}}'.format("yada")` I'll fix the above, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: using `%` looks more clean when your json variable is nested and has mutiple elemets like `b'{"ResourceRecordSet": {"Name": "%s","AliasTarget": {"HostedZoneId": "%s","DNSName": "%s"}}}' % (var1, var2,...)`

Answer (score 9):

instead of manipulating the string consider having the data as a python structure and then dump it to json

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['Machine Name'] = hostname
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"Machine Name": "machineA.host.com"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please see this example you will get some idea.**

```
test=f"Your order total is $ 150."

{"Total":"'+test+'"}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: And note that this question is over 8 years old, with two existing upvoted answers. Are you sure they don't already cover what you are showing here? Please don't repeat answers. See [answer].