# how to add variable to json

Tags: python, json

im trying to add a variable passed into a function into json but i keep getting an error, i used this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20777249/7502743), this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests

def interact(token):

    token_string = str(token)
    print token_string

    headers = {{'X-Username':'user','X-Token':'{0}'}}.format(token_string)

    print "token:"
    print headers


# main
login()
get_token = login()
interact(get_token)
```

this is the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: You forgot the quote around `{{'X-Username':'user','X-Token':'{0}'}}`

Comment: `{'X-Username': 'user', 'X-Token': token_string}` is the data structure you want to convert to JSON, as with `json.dumps()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm just confused by the input output the OP wants.  I guess

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply `format` to the string, not the dict that contains the string:

```
    headers = {
      {'X-Username':'user',
       'X-Token':'{0}'.format(token_string)
      }
    }
```

And, you can't put a `dict` in a `set`; you'll have to use a `list`.

```
headers = [
      {'X-Username':'user',
       'X-Token':'{0}'.format(token_string)
      }
]
```

Comment: It seems likely to me that `headers` should really just be a single dict, without any extra nesting (inside a list, another dict, a set, or otherwise) at all.

Comment: Why not just put token_string as value directly?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon You can; doing so just makes it hard to show how `format` was being misused in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you are trying to put a dict in a Set.

Consider:

```
foo = {"a"} # type(foo) <class 'set'>
foo.add({"b": 1}) # throws unhashable error
{"a", {"b": 1}} # equivalent to the above 2 lines
```

This is a fairly common error since set literals and dict literals both use curly braces:

```
bar = {"a", 1, "b", 2} # oops! 4 element set instead of dict with 2 k/v pairs
```